# Django send_mail results in Error 60, Operation Timed Out on Mac OSX

Tags: django, macos

Running into a very stange error. I'm running Django on my Mac OSX and when I tried to send an email from my application it hangs and gives me this error: "Error 60, Operation Timed Out". Exception Location: ...python2.6/socket.py in create_connection

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a local [OSX SMTP server](http://www.freshblurbs.com/how-enable-local-smtp-postfix-os-x-leopard)? if not then may I suggest this script which when used during development will dump any locally sent mail message to a file:

http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/96/